# Hibernate validator constraints in XML

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, bean-validation, spring-ws

I am using xml file to specify my constraints on an incoming request bean. I do this in a validation-constraints.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">
    <default-package>com.mathworks.internal.business.geoTypes
    </default-package>

    <bean class="GetStatesByCountryCodeRequest">
        <field name="countryCode">
            <constraint annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank" />

        </field>
    </bean>

</constraint-mappings>
```

I also need the countryCode to be only 2 characters long. I looked at the length validator provided by hibernate but it requires a min and a max value which I am guessing in my case should be 2 and 2. How can I specify the length constraint in a XML way? I cannot find any examples for that.

Comment: Open up the validation schema and look for what elements can go inside "constraint". My guess is there is probably a prop element or some name value pair element.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

```
<bean class="GetStatesByCountryCodeRequest">
        <field name="countryCode">
            <constraint annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank" />
            <constraint annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length">
                <element name="min">2</element>
                <element name="max">2</element>
            </constraint>

        </field>
    </bean>
```

This seems to have fixed the problem for now.

Comment: This looks good. The Hibernate Validator reference guide [describes in detail](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-mapping-xml-constraints) how to use XML constraint mappings.

Comment: Apologies for commenting on such an old question but I think that in your case the **Pattern** constraint would be more appropriate.

I had exactly the same need as you and I found that the Length (or Size in my case) violation message was not exactly right - "size must be between 2 and 2". 

Instead I used the Pattern constraint to define a regular expression to give the right length. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue the Pattern Constraint would be better I think.

```
<constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern" >
    <element name="regexp">[a-zA-Z]{2}</element>
</constraint>
```

This would define a length 2 string.

Instead of the violation message **"size must be between 2 and 2"**
you would have **"must match "[a-zA-Z]{2}""**