# Validation a request parameter against custom constraints using an XML file

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation

I'm working on a rest web service with spring and I'm trying to validate the received object:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sendResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public @ResponseBody String createResult(@Valid Result result, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {
}
```

and this is the validation method in the Result model:

```
@AssertTrue(message="votesCast field should be less or equal than registredVoters field")
      private boolean isValid() {
        return ((this.votesCast <= this.registredVoters) && (this.votesCast == this.validVotes + this.invalidVotes) );
      }
```

My problem is how to make my validation constraints configurable, I found [Hibernate validator constraints in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528464/hibernate-validator-constraints-in-xml).
But in this way how to put fields comparison in XML file like what I did in the isValid method?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may validate your models in Entity classes like this:

```
public class MultipartFile {

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    String name;
    //...
}
```

By default your error message will be

> size must be between 3 and 20.

To change the message you should use annotation like this:

```
@Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "your own message")
```

or you can create ValidationMessages.properties file in the resources directory, and write there something like this:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = Size must be between {min} and {max}. It is my own error message!
```

In your Post method will be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sendResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createResult(@ModelAttribute("image") @Valid
    MultipartFile image, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Maybe you need something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="User" table="USER">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the user detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: It's already done. My question is about using XML file instead of annotations

Comment: But why do you want use XML? Annotations are more readable and convenient.

Comment: The rules must be modifiable at any time without modifying the java code.

Comment: I edited my answer, please, let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: that's what I want but how to check votesCast <= registredVoters in that xml file?

Comment: Try to use [JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-xml-configuration.html#section-configuration-validation-xml).

Answer (score 0):

May it helps you. Validate your values using Spring Validator interface

1. Create validation class (note. You can add whatever conditions you want):

```
public class ResultValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return Result.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    Result r = (Result)o;
    if(r.votesCast > r.registredVoters){
       errors.rejectValue("registredVoters","RegistredVoters is not valid")
    }

    if(r.votesCast != r.validVotes + r.invalidVotes)){
       errors.rejectValue("votesCast","VotesCast is not valid")
    }
}
```

Where `rejectValue` parameter:

- 1'st  is field that is not valid
- 2'nd is message shown as message.

Also there you can use `ValidationUtils` to check for empty values and whitespaces.
2. In your controller add this code:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new ResultValidator());
}
```

3.Just add @Valid annotation in method parameters.

Check related post : http://javainsimpleway.com/spring-mvc-form-validation-with-custom-validator/